# How to move to next line when writing with turtle

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a couple of lines with turtle and I can't seem to find a way to go to the next line.

```
for i in range(0, len(all_keys)):
    if i == 6:
        break

    elem = dict1[all_keys[i]]

    output = elem + ": " + str(all_keys[i]) + "\n"

    print(output)

    write(output, font = style)

    del dict1[all_keys[i]]
```

I want to make it so that every iteration of the for cycle it moves to a new line